# Firefox doesn't support onfocusout

Tags: javascript, html

I am using onfocusout as an html attribute and some javascript code inside it. Nevertheless, the code works fine in Chrome and browsers powered by webkit engines but it doesn't work in Firefox, I haven't tested other browsers yet.

Is there any alternative for 'onfocusout' attribute which is supported at least by firefox and chrome?

Comment: Can you use `onblur` instead?

Comment: It may be worth adding more information to make your question more specific.  This will help others to provide more insightful feedback.  For example, add more detail about what you are trying to focus out, and provide code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what elements you are targeting but `blur` may work for you.

If that doesn't work for you then you may want to include a framework like `jQuery` which will help you with such cross browser issues.

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that jQuery could fix it :)

Answer (score 6):

Can you use [`onblur`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onblur)?

Comment: be aware that [`onfocusout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp) _bubbles_ while `onblur` does not.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is from 2011, just want to let everyone know that FireFox support for this attribute is now available since March 6th, 2017:  https://caniuse.com/#search=focusout